# Creating dir according to part of filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm looking to archive 10.0000+ files in a similar format:

files:

- 871-517-06461-1-120-01.pdf
- 871-517-06461-1-113-01.stp
- 871-517-06461-1-100-01.pdf

Example dir generated:
871-517-06461-1

- NAV
- TPD <- (files need to moved here)
- INS

files:

- 871-517-21541-1-100-01.pdf
- 871-517-21541-1-110-01.pdf
- 871-517-21541-1-113-01.stp

Example dir generated:
871-517-21541-1

- NAV
- TPD <- (files need to moved here)
- INS

What would be the way to archieve this? I came up with this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (*.pdf *.stp) do (
   set data=%%A
   echo file found !data:~0,16!
   for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB
   for /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%A") do set fextn=%%~xC
   for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%D in ("!fname!") do set folname=%%D
   echo folder name !folname:~0,16!
   if not exist "!folname:~0,16!" (
      echo Folder !folname:~0,16! does not exist, creating
      md "!folname:~0,16!"
      md "!folname:~0,16!\TPD"
      md "!folname:~0,16!\NAV"
      md "!folname:~0,16!\INS"
   ) else (
      echo Folder!folname:~0,16! already exists >> log.txt
   )
   echo Moving file %%A to folder !folname:~0,16!
   move "%%A" "!folname:~0,16!\TPD"
   )
echo Finished
pause
```

It's working, but how can i simplify this?
Also can i somehow change the character count with setting a variable?
Is it possible to remove the last - sign? So 871-517-06461-1 is named 871-517-064611.

Comment: cmd has quite limited features so it's much more trickier to do that compared to powershell

Comment: @phuclv thanks, but my understanding of powershell is also quite low.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Does a directory `871-517-21541-1` already exist, or does it behave to be created? where do the directories `NAV`, `TPD`, `INS` come from? Then you claim your code is not working and working at the same time; what is true? what, if, does not work? Please be specific!

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't working before, but i made it working...

I want:
It's working, but how can i simplify this? Also can i somehow change the character count with setting a variable? Is it possible to remove the last - sign? So 871-517-06461-1 is named 871-517-064611.

Comment: No, don't say the same again, explain what you really want to achieve so that somebody not sitting in front of your computer can understand too…

Comment: Much of the code you are using doesn't make any sense as to why you are using it.  There is no need to get the base file name split from the extension nor is there any need to use two FOR commands to do it. You then use a underscore as a delimiter but there are no underscores in your file name.   The whole point of using the delims option would be to split up the filename into multiple meta variables to use to make the directory.  This would be the most efficient and dynamic if the nodes can be different lengths.  Using a substring is only useful if the filename is always the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help you out?

It doesn't count characters, *(yours should have been `15` anyway)*, it isolates everything up to the fourth hyphen/dash, `-`.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    '(Set PATHEXT^=^) ^& %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe "%~dp0.":"?*-?*-?*-?*-*.pdf" "%~dp0.":"?*-?*-?*-?*-*.stp" 2^>NUL'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1-4,* Delims=-" %%H In ("%%~nG") Do (
    For %%L In (INS NAV TPD) Do If Not Exist "%%~dpG%%H-%%I-%%J-%%K\%%L\" MD "%%~dpG%%H-%%I-%%J-%%K\%%L"
    If Exist "%%~dpG%%H-%%I-%%J-%%K\TPD\" Move /Y "%%G" "%%~dpG%%H-%%I-%%J-%%K\TPD" 1>NUL
)
```

I haven't included all of the pointless `echo`ing of messages, so you'll need to adapt it for those if you really need them. Please however, do not make such changes before you've tested it. The only thing you may need to change is the source path; the above uses `%~dp0.` for the same location as the running batch file, you could change that to just `.`, for the current directory, or an actual relative or absolute path, if you prefer, *(taking care not to remove their enclosing double-quotes)*.

Comment: This works marvelous! I'm learning allot here.